# Mi mapa de Mapbox gl no ocupa todo el contenedor IONIC

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic, ionic-framework, mapbox

Hola y gracias de antemano por la ayuda, en mi ultima pregunta buscaba integrar un mapa en mi aplicación de ionic (bajo angular), me recomendaron mapbox y la verdad es que tiene muy buena pinta, pero me he topado con un problema, el mapa no ocupa todo el espacio del contenedor que le he asignado:

**Mi codigo**

contenedor del mapa:

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-buttons slot="start">
      <ion-menu-button></ion-menu-button>
    </ion-buttons>
    <ion-title>Puntos de interes</ion-title>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content [fullscreen]="true">
  <div id="mapa-mapbox"></div> <!-- Contenedor del mapa -->
</ion-content>
```

Estilos del contenedor:

```
#mapa-mapbox {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-color: yellow; // Solo para ver el tamaño
}
```

component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as Mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';
import { environment } from 'src/environments/environment';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab2',
  templateUrl: 'tab2.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['tab2.page.scss']
})

export class Tab2Page {

  public mapa: Mapboxgl.Map;
  constructor() {

  }

  ngOnInit() {
    Mapboxgl.accessToken = environment.mapkey;
    this.mapa = new Mapboxgl.Map({
      container: 'mapa-mapbox', // container id
      style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v11',
      center: [-74.5, 40], // starting position
      zoom: 4 // starting zoom
    });
    this.mapa.addControl(new Mapboxgl.NavigationControl());
  }
}
```

El resultado es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solución esperada: que el mapa ocupe toda la zona amarilla

EDIT 1:

probando con:

```
#mapa-mapbox {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: yellow; // Solo para ver el tamaño
}
```

consigo lo siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto denota que el mapa si esta ocupando todo el contenedor pero no se renderiza correctamente.

Cualquier ayuda es bienvenida.

Answer (score 0):

Tras varias horas de investigación, pruebas y errores he conseguido que funcione correctamente, simplemente hay que sustituir la llamada al mapa que hago en el ngOnit por lo siguiente:

```
  ionViewDidEnter() {
    this.buildMap();
  }
```